# How to align table in zurb foundation to the right of the div

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, html-table

So the whole question in the title.
Some code for illustration:

```
<div class="large-4 columns text-right">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" rowspan="3">
        <img src="
<%= image_path("meal1.png") %>
">
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="
<%= image_path("cook-vova.png") %>
" style="width:30px;">
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
      Домашние драники
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      Шеф повар: Владимир пастернак
    </td>
  </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you need: `<table align="right">`